Creating azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server_firewall_rule with for_each
Trying for 2 days create firewall rule but cant find the mistake.
I step down step by step and now using an example from hashicorp which also not works.
resource "azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server_firewall_rule" "vpn" {
  for_each = tomap({
    a = "112.234.12.1"
    b = "212.22.111.1",
    c = "22.111.22.1"
  })

  name             = "db-firewall-${each.key}"
  server_id        = azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server.mydb.id
  start_ip_address = each.value
  end_ip_address   = each.value
}

There is no firewall rule create by this code. Whats my bad?

Any errors running the code? Could you please post the output of terraform plan command?

Is terraform apply successful for this resource? Do you have the log output for azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server_firewall_rule.vpn for the apply command?

If the "azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server_firewall_rule" which you shared is the one which you're using in your configuration then as per the link this issue was due to extra comma in your 'tomap' function as it was a map not a set of strings @user6266369


Creating azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server_firewall_rule with for_each

As per the 'tomap' function, here the 'for_each' meta-argument were passed as a map not as the set of strings so we need to remove the extra comma in the second line of 'tomap'.
I tried a terraform configuration with reference to hashicorp registry with mentioned changes and I was able to provision the requirement successfully.
My terraform configuration:
resource "azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server" "mydb" {
  name                = "testvk-postgres-ser"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  version             = "12"
  administrator_login = "adminuser"
  administrator_password = "Password1234!"
  sku_name            = "GP_Standard_D4s_v3"
  storage_mb = 32768
  

  high_availability {
    mode = "SameZone"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server_firewall_rule" "vpn" {
  for_each = tomap({
    a = "112.234.12.1"
    b = "212.22.111.1"
    c = "22.111.22.1"
  })

  name             = "vkdb-firewall-${each.key}"
  server_id        = azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server.mydb.id
  start_ip_address = each.value
  end_ip_address   = each.value
}

Deployment succeeded:


